# can't send object via websocket

Tags: java, spring, websocket

So i'm trying to send an object from client->server & server->client with WebSocket. Sending object from client->server works fine, meanwhile server->client throw an exception

> org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token

Here is the class i'm trying to send

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
    public class TextMessage {
    private String sender;
    private String room;
    private String message;
}
```

and this is the code on the client-side

```
public class TelepatiClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebSocketClient client = new StandardWebSocketClient();
        WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(client);
        stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());
        stompClient.setTaskScheduler(new ConcurrentTaskScheduler());
        String url = "ws://localhost:8000/connect";
        StompSessionHandler handler = new TelepatiSessionHandler();
        stompClient.connect(url, handler);
        new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
    }
}

public class TelepatiSessionHandler extends StompSessionHandlerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void afterConnected(StompSession session, StompHeaders connectedHeaders) {
        session.subscribe("/room/global", this);
        session.send("/test", new TextMessage("test", "test", "test"));
    }
    @Override
    public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
        System.out.println(payload.toString());
    }
    @Override
    public void handleException(StompSession session, StompCommand command, StompHeaders headers, byte[] payload, Throwable exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        super.handleException(session, command, headers, payload, exception);
    }
}
```

and this is message controller on the server-side

```
@Controller
public class TelepatiController {
    @MessageMapping("/test")
    @SendTo("/room/global")
    public TextMessage getMessage(TextMessage message) {
        System.out.println("get message :" + message.toString());
        return new TextMessage("test2", "test2", "test2");
    }
}
```

i was able to run **System.out.println("get message :" + message.toString());**, but get message convertion exception on the client-side when returning **new TextMessage("test2", "test2", "test2");**. From my test before, returning a String object works fine, why returning TextMessage object not working? How can i send any object (in this case TextMessage) from server->client? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well the problem is the content. In this line:

```
stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());
```

You indicate that the client uses a json converter. So, your client is always expecting a JSON object.

But in your test, in this line:

```
 return new TextMessage("test2", "test2", "test2");
```

You are sending plain text. Due the StompClient is thrown an exception

> org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException

Because the message in text plain is not JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

I hope someone helps you, I had the same problem, what I did was tell the topler handler, to which I subscribe, the type of payload that will return.

This is the handler of my stompClient:

```java
public class TelepatiSessionHandler extends StompSessionHandlerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void afterConnected(StompSession session, StompHeaders connectedHeaders) {
        session.send("/test", new TextMessage("test", "test", "test"));
    }
    @Override
    public void handleException(StompSession session, StompCommand command, StompHeaders headers, byte[] payload, Throwable exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        super.handleException(session, command, headers, payload, exception);
    }
}
```

And this is the handler for the topic to which I subscribe

```java
  WebSocketClient client = new StandardWebSocketClient();
  WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(client);
  stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());
  stompClient.setTaskScheduler(new ConcurrentTaskScheduler());
  String url = "ws://localhost:8000/connect";
  StompSessionHandler handler = new TelepatiSessionHandler();
  StompSession session =  stompClient.connect(url, handler).get();
  session.subscribe("/room/global", new StompFrameHandler() {

      @Override
      public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers) {
             return TextMessage.class;
      }

      @Override
      public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
              TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) payload;
          System.out.println(textMessage.toString());
      }
  });
```

Here is a complete example:
https://github.com/jaysridhar/spring-websocket-client/blob/master/src/main/java/sample/Application.java